# VBA Excel - Index Match com duas condições

Tags: query, algoritmo-de-busca, excel-vba, índices, criteria

Tenho uma planilha com várias abas.
Na primeira aba tenho a seguinte tabela:
[image: Aba 1]

Na aba 2 digito o cliente e o tipo, e desejo que retorne o ID.

Para isto estou utilizando o seguinte código em VBA:

```
tipo = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
cliente = Range("D5").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Aba 1").[Tabela1[ID]], WorksheetFunction.Match(cliente & tipo, Sheets("Aba 1").[Tabela1[CLIENTE]] & Sheets("Aba 1").[Tabela1[TIPO]], 0))
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer retornar o valor.
Tentei de várias maneiras, até mesmo utilizando o EVALUATE ou dividindo a função por partes mas não consegui chegar no resultado esperado.

Como devo fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Tabela1[ID],MATCH(1,(cliente=Tabela1[CLIENTE])*(" & tipo & "=Tabela1[TIPO]),0))"
```

Dica extraída deste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426054/how-to-use-index-and-match-in-vba-excel-with-multiple-criterias)